# Pagination returning the same posts on each page

Tags: php

Each page returns the same posts when you click "older posts". This was working fine at one time, but now it's not. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset'=> 0, 'category'=> '-1, -9, -16, -17, -119, -318' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<div class="blog-post-wrap">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<div class="post-thumb blog-index">
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );
} 
?>
</div>

<div class="title-meta-wrap">   

<?php if (strlen($post->post_title) > 75) {
echo substr(the_title($before = '', $after = '', FALSE), 0, 75) . '...'; } else {
the_title();
} ?>
</a>
<p><span class="theauthor"><?php the_date(); ?> <span style="color:#EC7906;"> / </span><?php the_author(); ?> </span></p>

</div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

I was able to remove this:

```
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
```

And go with just this:

```
get_posts( $args );
```

And pagination worked but the page only returned one post per page. Any thoughts?

Comment: How are the posts stored. Does the function being called in get_post return database results? Try checking the array returned by the function using print_r(array) because if the array being returned has the same posts each time it might be within the get_post function that is causing you problems.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes there are results being returned. It's just the same results for each page.

Comment: Okay. Check if paged variable is indeed being incremented if it is and the posts are being stored in a database make sure you properly set the LIMIT ie LIMIT ($paged * 10) , 10 where 10 is the number of posts per page you can use any number there.

Comment: Where would I set LIMIT at?

Comment: I am assuming you are using MYSQL or MYSQLI in that case you would set the limit in the SQL statement. SELECT * from `posts` WHERE [add your criteria here] LIMIT (page * $posts_per_page) , $posts_per_page. The first part of limit will tell it where to start getting the posts and the second part says how many posts to get. So when $page increases the starting position of your results will increase by the number per page.